# online option with eqexam package (undefined \eq@RadioCheck@driver)

Tags: online

When I try to compile the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[online,nosolutions]{eqexam}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{exam}{Description}
\begin{problem}[1]
Question
\begin{answers}{2} 
\bChoices 
\Ans0 True \eAns 
\Ans1 False \eAns 
\eChoices
\end{answers}
\begin{solution}
False
\end{solution}
\end{problem}
\end{exam}
\end{document}
```

I got the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument>\eq@RadioCheck@driver
1.12 \Ans
1 False\eAns
```

(Everything fine without online option)

Any idea ?

Comment: it is a bug in acrotex/eqexam, in the newest version it has renamed the command but not adapted everything. Write the author a mail. (In texlive it works, as it still uses older versions).

Answer (score 0):

From the author of the package, add:

```
\makeatletter
\let\eq@RadioCheck@driver= \eq@Radio@driver
\makeatother
```

The package will be updated soon.